# Connection localhost:8069 with OpenErp installed in ubuntu 12.04 LTS not possible without a internet connection. Why..?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

i successfully worked for a long time with OpenErp 7.0 installed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
normally localhost:8069 will display my front page to login.
but today it doesnt display anything . just a white page.
After making the computer internet connected, the front page (login) opens as normal.
why this happens so..?

Comment: It's strange, it should work without internet connection. Do you see any error in the log file?

Comment: Try to open it in another browser or in a new Incognito Window